# How to format row in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, row, multiple-columns

IM trying to figuring out how I can change my code thats its looking like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ws8j.png)

My looks like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP7oQ.png)

And heres my code

```
    return Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          DatbaseService.instance.createorGetConversation(uid, uid,
              (String _conversationID) {
            NavigationService.instance.navigateToRoute(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return MeineBeitraege(
                  _conversationID,
                  widget.uid,
                  widget.username,
                  widget.url,
                  widget.email,
                );
              }),
            );
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
                height: 35,
                width: 35,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: widget.url != null && widget.url != 'profilepictureer'
                    ? Image.network(
                        widget.url,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                    : Image.asset(
                        'assets/profilepictureer.png') // Your widget is here when image is no available.
                ),
          ),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3)),
        ),
      ),
      Column(children: [
        RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: widget.username, // _snapshot.data['username']
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),

            children: <InlineSpan>[
              WidgetSpan(
                  alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
                  baseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                  child: SizedBox(width: 4)),
              TextSpan(
                //"${comment.data()['comment']}"
                text: widget.comment,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(widget.timeago),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text('${widget.commentlikes} likes'),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                widget.onTap();
                if (!widget.focusNode.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                  setState(() {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(widget.focusNode);
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Text('Reply'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
           widget.commentcount != null && widget.commentcount > 0
            ? Container(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          if (viewreplies) {
                            setState(() {
                              viewreplies = false;
                            });
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              viewreplies = true;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        child: viewreplies == true
                            ? Text(
                                '———View replies(${widget.commentcount})',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                              )
                            : Text(
                                '———Hide replies(${widget.commentcount})',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                              )),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
     
      ]),
      
      const Spacer(),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () => likecomment(widget.commentdataid),
        child: widget.likes.contains(uid)
            ? Icon(
                Icons.star,
                size: 25,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              )
            : Icon(
                Icons.star_border_outlined,
                size: 25,
              ),
      )
    ]);
```

What I want then is the exact same function as instagram has like when tapping on  ViewReplies I wanna show ht comments of the comments . Hope anyone can help .If you need more information please leave a comment

OK so heres my updated code . First a lsitviewbuidler

```
----- - - - -- 
return Listviewbuilder
---- - - - -
child: Column(children: [
                                          CommentsWidget(
```

Then the commentswidget is the Lisle seperat in a stateful

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wi = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Column(
          children:[

           ListTile( -------)
-- - -- - - 
CommentsComments(),
```

CommentsComments() is the second listview again in a sepereat stateful  with the second listtile

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
   child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('videos')
            .doc(widget.videoid)
            .collection('comments')
            .doc(widget.id)
            .collection("commentcomment")
            .orderBy('time', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
    --...
ListTile()
```

Answer (score 1):

for creating an Instagram like comment section UI you can check the below code.
I have added a hardcoded list for display purpose you can insert your own server data with logic to differentiate between both list views.
For this UI I have created a normal comment object having all replies to that user in replies list such as

```
single user comment object
    {
          'name': 'person 1',
          'message': 'Some text message from person 1',
          'replies': [
            {
              'name': 'person 2',
              'message': 'Some text message from person 2',
            },
            {
              'name': 'person 3',
              'message': 'Some text message from person 3',
            },
          ]
        },
```

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<dynamic> commentList = [
    {
      'name': 'person 1',
      'message': 'Some text message from person 1',
      'replies': [
        {
          'name': 'person 2',
          'message': 'Some text message from person 2',
        },
        {
          'name': 'person 3',
          'message': 'Some text message from person 3',
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      'name': 'person 4',
      'message': 'Some text message from person 4',
      'replies': []
    },
    {
      'name': 'person 5',
      'message': 'Some text message from person 5',
      'replies': [
        {
           'name': 'person 6',
          'message': 'Some text message from person 6',
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello World"),),
        body: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: commentList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(children: [
                ListTile(
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  title: Text(commentList[index]['name']),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.fiber_new),
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    itemCount: commentList[index]['replies'].length ?? 0,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      return ListTile(
                        contentPadding:
                            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                         leading: Icon(Icons.pages),
                        title: Text(commentList[index]['replies'][i]['name'] ),
                      );
                    })
              ]);
            }));
  }
}
```

Run this cord in dartpad and refactor it according to your use.
[image]

Comment: i will trying this and give you some feedback give me 5 minute -10minutes

Comment: OK need some more time like 10 -15 minutes hopefully

Comment: @yjanjanyj yes please.

Comment: ok it works perfect I think but when tapping on view replies the comment is not on the correct position. it is like directly under the parent comment . lets first fix that then the other problem .I will update my code so you can see how im doing it I should say I call listviewbuilder then seperat staftefulwidget which is the Lisle and that was working perfect.

Comment: ok I updated my code I hope you can see what I do wrong so again the second list tile is directly under the first one  instead of like it looks like in instagram

Comment: brother? are you're there

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can provide only the code of both listviews because right now we cannot see what you have written inside listview.builders which are causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is too late but it can help.

In Android Studio go to

File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Dart

and increase the value of Line , my case increased the length to 500 then hit CTRL +ALT+L for Windows and Command + Option +L for MAC.